# Realm: When or where do I need to check if an object has been invalidated?

Tags: objective-c, realm

Kinda new to Realm and I just took over a project which uses Realm. So I of course access in a lot of spots in my app our realm objects. Recently I've noticed that in 3 specific spots we get more and more crashes about Realm objects that have been invalidated or deleted. In all other spots I hardly ever get a crash..even though I do it always the same. So let's say we have a Realm object User *user, I always call user.firstname. In one particular spot I get often a crash so I assume I should check there if it has been invalidated with if(![user isInvalidated]). But why? Or how do I know when I need to check for that?

Or do I need to check it every single time when I access an object? What about if I pass a realm object in an Array to another method -> Do I need to check if after the passage again?

And more over: What do I need to do if it has been invalidated?

Would be glad for any help, this whole topic seems quite confusing

Comment: Ask yourself under what conditions would an object be invalidated in the first place and then work through the logic to determine why that object is being accessed afterwards. In other words, if you cast a Realm results object (e.g. a bunch of user objects) to an Array. Then modify one of those user objects (in the array) and someone else deletes that user object from Realm, *then* you attempt to update the user object (in Realm), that would lead to an invalidated object because it no longer exists. Do you have some example code to demonstrate the issue? Are you calling invalidate?

Comment: Hmm actually there is no reason this could happen. My approach is now look at all crashes and just check the top 5 where this happens for invalidation. Because our app is rather simple: A user imports his roster (during that time the app is blocked) to our server and to the local db. Afterwards all data is accessed via result objects but not changed. Maybe transferred to an array etc, but not any property changed unless a new import is started. So there is no case where they can really be invalidated